# Kendo: core VS ui.core

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a page that has javascript to convert an input to a MaskedTextBox:

```
$("#PhoneNumber").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "(000) 000-0000"
});
```

Other than reference to 'jquery.js', if I include a reference to just 'kendo.ui.core.min.js' the MaskedTextBox works as expected. If I only include a reference to 'kendo.core.min.js' it doesn't work.

I would have thought that the 'kendo.ui.core.min.js' would need 'kendo.core.min.js' but this doesn't appear to be the case.

What is the difference between these two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of unfortunate naming:

- kendo.core.min.js contains Kendo UI core functionality that is used everywhere, for both the OSS and commercial product
  (e.g. the Observable and Widget classes)
- kendo.ui.core.min.js is the complete OSS bundle which includes kendo.core.js and all widgets

So, in the first case, "core" relates to "core functionality", and in the second case, it relates to the product name of Telerik's open source product "Kendo UI Core".